# Windows batch doesn't execute

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying the below code to ftp a file from desktop to host.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set >set
setlocal
SET infile= 
SET outfile=
SET defuser=
SET defpwd=
:startover
IF "%defuser%"=="" (
set /p defuser="Enter User ID: " 
)
IF "%defpwd%"=="" (
set /p defpwd="Enter Password: "
)

set /p infile="Enter the path name:" 

set /p outfile="Enter the target filename:"

@echo **************entering ftp step**************
echo user %defuser%> ftpcmd.dat
echo %defpwd%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo ascii>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %infile% '%outfile%'>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bye>> ftpcmd.dat

@echo ***********************execute ftp**************
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat x.xx.xxx.xxx

@echo ****************executed ftp***********************
exit/b
```

However, the ftp -n -s: ftpcmd.dat never gets executed,I mean, the ftp never happens, instead the code goes back to Enter User ID. I don't know why it doesn't obey exit command.

Any suggestion to this would be helpful.

Regards,
Vish

Comment: you have a label `:startover` which I do not see you `goto` it can only go to that label if you tell it too. are you not showing all the code?

Comment: another possibility: the batch file is named `ftp.bat` (or `ftp.cmd`), which would mean it's recursively starting itself instead of actually ftp-ing. (yes, those things happen...)

Comment: @Stephan yes... was just about to mention that as well.!! That is more than likely the case here.. `:)`

Comment: I have the given the full code here. The reason for the label without GOTO is that, Initially I thought of having a code based on some condition.  But, the basic code / core functionality itself didn't work in my case.

Comment: ok, is your batch file called `ftp.cmd` or `ftp.bat` ?

Comment: I'm little confused. The file where I have the above code (saved in .bat format) is transfer.bat. The code creates the required simple ftp commands inside the file as ftpcmd.dat. Apolgoies, if that didn't anwer your question.

Comment: hmm. ok, well try this, then I will believe you `:)` in your batch file change the `ftp` line to this line and try the script again.. `ftp.exe -n -s:ftpcmd.dat x.xx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Wonderful ! that worked :)

Comment: So then that means you have a file called `ftp.cmd` or `ftp.cmd` in your directory somewhere.. find it, delete or rename `;)`

Comment: …or use `"%__AppDir__%ftp.exe" -n -s:ftpcmd.dat x.xx.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: Sure. I will find that culprit;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment, here's an example of your file, written in order that you don't have to move, rename or delete any instances of `ftp.com`, `ftp.exe`, `ftp.bat`, `ftp.cmd`, `ftp.vbs`, `ftp.vbe`, `ftp.js`, `ftp.jse`, `ftp.wsf`, `ftp.wsh`, `ftp.msc` etc. in the current directory first.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "defuser="
Set "defpwd="

:startover
If Not Defined defuser Set /P "defuser=Enter User ID: "
If Not Defined defpwd Set /P "defpwd=Enter Password: "

Set "infile="
Set /P "infile=Enter the path name: "
If Not Defined infile GoTo startover

Set "outfile="
Set /P "outfile=Enter the target filename: "
If Not Defined outfile GoTo startover

Echo  *************** entering ftp step ***************
(   Echo user %defuser%
    Echo %defpwd%
    Echo ascii
    Echo lcd
    Echo put %infile% '%outfile%'
    Echo bye
)>"ftpcmd.dat"

Echo  ****************** execute ftp ******************
"%__AppDir__%ftp.exe" -n -s:ftpcmd.dat x.xx.xxx.xxx

Echo ****************** executed ftp ******************
Exit /B
```